# Python print_r which returns value instead of printing it

Tags: python

Is it possible, in Python, to do something similar to:

```
echo 'Content of $var is ', print_r($var, TRUE);
```

in PHP?

I have a variable var and I would like to assign its contents in a readable form to a string, for example:

```
str = 'Hello. '
str = str + var
```

Comment: str is a built in python function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use `str(var)`, as in:

```py
s = 'Hello. ' + str(var)
```

Here, `str` is a built-in function, and has nothing to do with the `str` you have in your script. When coding in Python, please avoid names that coincide with the names of [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

An alternative way is to use the string formatting operator `%`:

```py
s = 'Hello. %s' % var
```

Comment: str() will return an encoded string. If you want a unicode string, which you usually do, unicode() is what you want.

Comment: Also, Python3's string substitution is different. http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#formatting-strings

Comment: In addition to `s = 'Hello. %s' % var` you should write also `s = 'Hello. {}'.format(var)`, which is available since Python 2.6 (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and is a lot more flexible than `%` operator.

Answer (score 5):

### Three methods of achieving what you want

There are at least three ways of doing this in python:

1. The best one - using **`.format()` method of string objects** (available since Python 2.6):

   Using simple replacement:

   ```py
   print 'Content of var is {}'.format(var)
   ```

   Using referencing by name:

   ```py
   print 'Content of var is {var}'.format(**locals())
   ```
2. The *always-working* one - **formatting operation**:

   Using simple replacement:

   ```py
   print 'Content of var is %s' % var
   ```

   Using referencing by name:

   ```py
   print 'Content of var is %(var)s' % locals()
   ```
3. **Concatenation**:

   ```py
   print 'Content of var is ' + str(var)
   ```

### Difference between `%r` and `%s` in formatting operations

`%r` differs from `%s`, because `%r` is replaced with **representation** of the variable, and `%s` is replaced with the variable **converted to string**. You can see it clearly on the example below:

```
>>> class MyClass():
    def __str__(self):
        return '__str__() result'
    def __repr__(self):
        return '__repr__() result'


>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> '%r' % mc
'__repr__() result'
>>> '%s' % mc
'__str__() result'
```

Did it help?

Comment: Nice summary of how to format strings (the ordering by preference is great to see written out).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(variable)
```

Note:

```
var = 'xxx'
s = 'Hello. %s' % var
print s
```